# How to reduce latency for 'cma_alloc'?

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working with cma reserved memory and getting high latency.

Is there any way to reduce cma allocation latency?

Comment: In original post the first sentence was a simplified version of the third one, so I have performed corresponded editing. Also, on Stack Overflow phrases like "Any help would be highly appreciated." are tent to be removed, as they carry no information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The latency is probably due to the kernel migrating movable pages (for block device caches etc.) out of the CMA in order to get a large enough contiguous region for your request. One way to avoid the latency is to reserve a specific memory block for your device in the device tree, so it doesn't have to allocate from the global CMA pool.

**The following assumes you are developing an embedded system that uses device trees and can modify driver code to make use of a reserved memory region.**

If reserving a memory region specifically for your device, you can reserve the region statically or dynamically (letting the kernel determine the start address of the region).  See [reserved-memory.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt) for details.

Set the `no-map` property to stop the kernel mapping the memory as part of its standard system memory.

DO NOT set the `reusable` property if you do not want the memory to be used for temporary storage by other parts of the kernel (block page cache etc.).

If you want to allocate coherent DMA memory from the buffer, set `compatible = "shared-dma-pool";`. Although the pool is "shared", it is only shared by devices that specifically use this reserved memory region.

In your device node, set the `memory-region` property as a phandle referring to the reserved memory region.

For example:

```
/ {
         /* ... */

         reserved-memory {
                 #address-cells = <1>;
                 #size-cells = <1>;
                 ranges;

                 my_dev_reserved: region_my_dev_buffer {
                         compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
                         no-map;
                         size = <0x02000000>; /* 32 MiB size */
                         alignment = <0x1000>; /* 4 KiB alignment */
                 };
         };

         /* ... */

         my_dev: mydev@xxxx {
                 compatible = "foo,barbaz-1.0";
                 /* ... */
                 memory-region = <&my_dev_reserved>;
                 /* ... */
         };

         /* ... */
};
```

In your device driver "probe" function, you can call `of_reserved_mem_device_init(hwdev);` (where `hwdev` is a pointer to the `struct device` for your hardware decice, which is usually embedded inside some other structure such as `struct platform_device`). A return value of `0` indicates that the device will use the device-specific reserved memory for coherent DMA memory allocations (if the region's `compatible` string is `"shared-dma-pool"`, otherwise coherent DMA memory allocations will fall back to using the global pool.

If `of_reserved_mem_device_init(hwdev);` was successful, you should call `of_reserved_mem_release(hwdev);` in your device driver "remove" function to free the allocated resources.  (You may also need to call it in the error clean-up code of your "probe" function.)

Comment: I want dynamic allocation with large size buffer and reusable property, not static allocation, your answered is useful for static allocation.

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi Thanks for your thoughts. TBH, I've always found the CMA to be a little bit unreliable for allocating large buffers of similar size to the CMA region, due to fragmentation caused by allocations from other drivers. However, I haven't used it for a few years, so maybe things have improved.